# Creating a new column using exisitng values from another column

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a table with product, price and date_start attributes. The last one tells on what day price changed.

```
product    price    date_start
A          100      2010-01-20
A          23       2010-04-12
A          120      2012-05-03
....
```

I want to modify the table to add date_end column.

```
product    price    date_start    date_end
A          100      2010-01-20    2010-04-12
A          23       2010-04-12    2012-05-03
A          120      2012-05-03    2015-03-18
....
```

Would appreciate any hints on how to do it with sqlite

Comment: you mean ALTER TABLE table_name ADD new_column_name column_definition; ?

Answer (score 0):

Use `lead()`:

```
select t.*, lead(date_start) over (partition by product order by date_start) as date_end
from t;
```

If you have an "infinite" future date that you want to use instead of `NULL` for the last record for each product, then use the 3-argument form:

```
select t.*,
       lead(date_start, 1, <default date here>) over (partition by product order by date_start) as date_end
from t;
```